# Complex object in a query string

Tags: http, post, get, query-string

How can I have this structure in a query string?

```
"properties": {
        "list": [
            {
                "label": "bye",
                "value": "world"
            },
            {
                "label": "hello",
                "value": "mars"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I've tried it with `properties[][list][label]=bye&properties[][list][value]=world&properties[0][label]=hello&properties[0][value]=mars` and also with `properties[][list][label]=bye&properties[][list][value]=world&properties[][list][label]=hello&properties[][list][value]=mars`, none of them worked. I built them in php with `http_build_query`.

I need to have this structure in a query string because I have to send the data along with some other stuff with POST to a PHP site.

Comment: How about sending it as a JSON string? the newlines are just for human reading, you can just do it all in a single line and then use `json_decode` in PHP.

Comment: Well the problem is that I can't send it via PHP, instead I have to use something similar to cURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two errors in your query string:

- `properties` is an object, so there's no need to use `[]` to add elements.
- `list` is an array, so you must use numeric indexes in the query string.

The correct query string is:

```
?properties[list][0][label]=bye
&properties[list][0][value]=world
&properties[list][1][label]=hello
&properties[list][1][value]=mars
```

*(multi-lined for readability)*

Comment: Yes, thank you that's it! And so fast. Thank you so much.

Comment: @User2093587239023: you're welcome! Be sure to mark the answer as accepted if that solved your problem.

Comment: Yes I will, but StackOverflow said I have to wait 8 minutes ;)